# How to edit a list of child entities in Spring 3 MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How would I edit an entity with child rows in Spring 3 MVC?

I'd like a form like:

```
<forms:form>
  <p>Parent name <forms:input path="model.name" type="text" /></p>
  <p>Children:
    <ul>
      <s:foreach in="${model.children}" var="${child} varStatus="row">
        <li>
          name: <forms:input path="model.children[${row.index}].name" />
          <button name="?">delete</button>
        </li>
      </s:foreach>
    </ul>
  </p>
  <p><button name="?">add child</button></p>
</forms:form>
```

I'm having a lot of trouble getting this to work in Spring 3.

I would love to be able to:

- edit child properties inline on the parent's form, with validation etc.
- delete children inline on the parent's form
- add children inline on the parent's form

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out jqGrid?

If you want DIY, then have a nested loop and create the crud links in the inner loop. 
An HTML table might be appropriate for presentation.

Here is part of the "child" loop.

```
<tbody style="background: #ccc">
                    <c:forEach items="${parent.children}" var="work">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${work.id}</td>
                            <td>${work.title}</td>
                            <spring:url var="editWorkUrl" value="/work/edit/${work.id}" />
                            <spring:url var="deleteWorkUrl" value="/work/delete/${work.id}" />
                            <td><a href="${editWorkUrl}">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="${deleteWorkUrl}">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: jqGrid is for displaying tabular data using javascript. My question is about databinding multi-level entities in Spring MVC. I don't see how the two overlap.

Comment: jqGrid was one answer and it does work for parent/child entities even if you don't see how. My other answer was how to do it "by hand".